# Extract covariance from data frame in a loop

Tags: r, matrix, sampling

```
sample_size <- 200                                       
sample_meanvector <- c(3, 4)                                   
sample_covariance_matrix <- matrix(c(2, 1, 1, 2),
                                   ncol = 2)

# create bivariate normal distribution
sample_distribution <- mvrnorm(n = sample_size,
                               mu = sample_meanvector, 
                               Sigma = sample_covariance_matrix)

#Convert the datatype
df_sample_distribution <- as.data.frame(sample_distribution)

df_sample_distribution$Y <- (1 + df_sample_distribution$V1*2 + df_sample_distribution$V2 + rnorm(200,0,1))
colnames(df_sample_distribution)[1] <- "X1"
colnames(df_sample_distribution)[2] <- "X2"
```

Code above is the one I use to generate a bivariate normal distribution vectors and code below is the code to run regression over the generated data.

```
Test2 <- lm( Y ~ X1, data = df_sample_distribution)
#to extract only specific coefficients
summary(Test)$coefficients[2,1]
```

My question is whether there is a way such that I can regenerate data and run regression over it for 200 times and save all the outputs in a list. Here is the pseudo code in my head.

```
for (){
  #generate data
  
  for ()
  {
    #extract coeffiients and insert them in a list 
  }
}
```

In simple terms,

step 1: create data

step 2: run regression over it

step 3: get the coefficient (hopefully save them in a list)

I am looking for code that can loop through step 1 to 3 for 200 times and save everything results. Any ideas or inspirations are welcomed. Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your code into a `for`-loop like your pseudo code:

```r
library(MASS)

iterations <- 10 # In your example this should be 200

sample_size <- 200                                       
sample_meanvector <- c(3, 4)                                   
sample_covariance_matrix <- matrix(c(2, 1, 1, 2),
                                   ncol = 2)

# create output data.frame
df_output <- data.frame(iteration = integer(0), coeff = double(0))

# loop over data generation and regression
for (i in seq_len(iterations)) {
  sample_distribution <- mvrnorm(n = sample_size,
                                 mu = sample_meanvector, 
                                 Sigma = sample_covariance_matrix)
  
  #Convert the datatype
  df_sample_distribution <- as.data.frame(sample_distribution)
  
  df_sample_distribution$Y <- (1 + df_sample_distribution$V1*2 + df_sample_distribution$V2 + rnorm(200,0,1))
  colnames(df_sample_distribution)[1] <- "X1"
  colnames(df_sample_distribution)[2] <- "X2"
  
  df_output[i, 1] <- i
  df_output[i, 2] <- summary(lm( Y ~ X1, data = df_sample_distribution))$coefficients[2,1]
}
```

This returns `df_output` containing coefficients for each iteration:

```r
   iteration    coeff
1          1 2.647886
2          2 2.274654
3          3 2.447453
4          4 2.451471
5          5 2.568877
6          6 2.428295
7          7 2.440396
8          8 2.478357
9          9 2.477211
10        10 2.367012
```

Comment: That actually helps a lot, thank you so very much!!!!!!!! You worked the magic!!!!